# Including common code across layouts in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have a block of code that contains page configuration like shown below. I'd like to use this across my view layouts in CakePHP. I could use the PHP `include` function but I want to stay in line with CakePHP convention. So I tried putting this code in an element, a common file etc but no matter what I do the code block (and defined variables) doesnt seem to be available to the page.Can someone advise what I am doing wrong?

I also tried putting this in a layout but these code blocks are shared across layouts as well - so how do I include the same code snippet across layouts?

```
<?php
/* Template variables */
$template = array(
    'name'          => 'Mywebsite.com',
    'boxed'         => false,
    'active_page'   => basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
);

/* Primary navigation array (the primary navigation will be created automatically based on this array) */
$primary_nav = array(
    array(
        'name'  => 'Home',
        'url'   => Router::url('/home')
    ),
    array(
        'name'  => 'Features',
        'url'   => Router::url('/features')
    ),
    array(
        'name'  => 'Pricing',
        'url'   => Router::url('/pricing')
    ),
    array(
        'name'  => 'Contact',
        'url'   => Router::url('/contact')
    ),
    array(
        'name'  => 'About',
        'url'   => Router::url('/about')
    ),
    array(
        'name'  =>  'Login',
        'url'   =>  Router::url('/login')
    )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This in config file. While reading the file you can use it.

Below is example:-
create a file in Config Folder example_config.php and Add this code in it.

```
 $template = array(
    'name'          => 'Mywebsite.com',
    'boxed'         => false,
    'active_page'   => basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
);
```

Use  variables With this method in controller:-

```
   Configure::load('example_config','default');

   $first = Configure::read('name');
   echo  $first;
```

It Will display

```
Mywebsite.com
```